# DSE 6.7 solr searh always return empty

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am using DSE 6.7 with 3 nodes, 128 virtual node per node.
I have configed solr a IKAnalyzer for search Chinese text. It test ok in solr console like below image:
[image]

but it is not ok test in query, always return empty data.

[image]

then I test is in cassandra devCenter, it is the same, return data count is not empty but data always empty?
[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me with that?

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.tax_law (
    type text,
    cityname text,
    items text,
    title text,
    link text,
    accessory text,
    content text,
    article date text,
    number text,
    pubdate date,
    valid text,
    PRIMARY KEY (title, type, date)
);
```

Solr schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">   <types>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
    <fieldType class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.types.SimpleDateField" name="SimpleDateField"/>
    <fieldType name="text_ik" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index" useSmart="false" >
                <tokenizer class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query" useSmart="true" >
                <tokenizer class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>   </types>   <fields>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="title" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="items" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="article_date" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cityname" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="number" type="StrField"/>
    <field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="pubdate" type="SimpleDateField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="content" stored="true" type="text_ik"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="link" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="type" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="valid" type="StrField"/>
    <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="accessory" type="StrField"/>
    <field name="searchText" type="text_ik" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />   </fields>   <uniqueKey>(title,type,article_date)</uniqueKey>

  <defaultSearchField>searchText</defaultSearchField>  
     <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR" />    <copyField source="title" dest="searchText" />   <copyField source="content" dest="searchText" />   </schema>
```

Post my simple table schema and test data here, query in below is return empty.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.test(
    id int,
    title text,
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, title)
);


select * from rawdata.test;
select * from rawdata.test where solr_query='{"q":"content:税法"}';
select * from rawdata.test where solr_query='{"q":"title:国税局"}';
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your schema for this table - both CQL table definition, and `schema.xml` for Solr Can you also check that data is actually in the table? Maybe the index became invalid...

Comment: Also you can join DataStax Academy Slack: http://academy.datastax.com/slack - there is #dse-search channel there where people could help more operatively

Comment: For my first comment - you may try to rebuild index with `REBUILD SEARCH INDEX on ks.table;`

Comment: I do upload schema.xml and reload the core.

Comment: It seems a bug of DSE6.7 solr, I do not know how it pass the release test. I replace primary key with integer number it works, but it still can not display it, all data looks like ????

Comment: Can I down grade to 6.0.4 with 6.7 cassandra, graph, solr tables?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce and one thing is not clear for me: seems `type` is a keyword and I am simply not sure if table create / index creation went well at all.

Table creation with provided

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.tax_law ( type text, cityname text, items text, title text, link text, accessory text, content text, article date text, number text, pubdate date, valid text, PRIMARY KEY (title, type, date) );
```

does not work

Do you get correct data from pure cassandra query without using dse search?

Comment: Can you try:```

Comment: I have test with a very simple table without "type", it is the same error.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.test(
 id int,
 title text,
 content text,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, title)
);

Comment: Only this works, Primary key only has id. but data shows all like "???"

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.test(
 id int,
 title text,
 content text,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

@peter I have made some experiment and with default StrText and IK, everything works as expected:

```
    cqlsh
    Connected to master at 127.0.0.1:9042.
    [cqlsh 5.0.1 | DSE 6.7.0 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]
    Use HELP for help.
    cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE rawdata WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> CREATE TABLE rawdata.test (
       ...     id int,
       ...     title text,
       ...     content text,
       ...     solr_query text,
       ...     PRIMARY KEY (id, title));
    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> CREATE TABLE rawdata.test2 (
       ...     id text,
       ...     title text,
       ...     content text,
       ...     solr_query text,
       ...     PRIMARY KEY (id, title));
    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON rawdata.test;

    Warnings :
    Please remember this operation is DC specific and should be repeated on each desired DC.

    cqlsh> CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON rawdata.test2;

    Warnings :
    Please remember this operation is DC specific and should be repeated on each desired DC.

    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> insert into rawdata.test2(id, title, content) values ('簇', '我喜欢吃鱼', '我喜欢吃鱼');
    cqlsh> insert into rawdata.test(id, title, content) values (1, '我喜欢吃鱼', '我喜欢吃鱼');
    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title | content | solr_query
    ----+-------+---------+------------

    (0 rows)
    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test2 WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title | content | solr_query
    ----+-------+---------+------------

    (0 rows)
    cqlsh> 
    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test2 WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title | content | solr_query
    ----+-------+---------+------------

    (0 rows)
    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test2 WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title | content | solr_query
    ----+-------+---------+------------

    (0 rows)
    cqlsh> commit search index on rawdata.test;
    cqlsh> commit search index on rawdata.test2;
    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test2 WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title      | content    | solr_query
    ----+------------+------------+------------
     簇 | 我喜欢吃鱼 | 我喜欢吃鱼 |       null

    (1 rows)
    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title      | content    | solr_query
    ----+------------+------------+------------
      1 | 我喜欢吃鱼 | 我喜欢吃鱼 |       null
```

A I am also not able to reproduce the issue with IK analyzer:

```
    automaton@ip-10-200-175-18:~$ cqlsh
    Connected to master at 127.0.0.1:9042.
    [cqlsh 5.0.1 | DSE 6.7.0 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]
    Use HELP for help.
    cqlsh> describe active search index schema on rawdata.test2;

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
      <types>
        <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
        <fieldType name="text_ik" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer type="index" useSmart="false" >
                    <tokenizer class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKTokenizerFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query" useSmart="true" >
                    <tokenizer class="org.wltea.analyzer.lucene.IKTokenizerFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
      </types>
      <fields>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="title" type="StrField"/>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="content" type="text_ik"/>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="id" type="StrField"/>
      </fields>
      <uniqueKey>(id,title)</uniqueKey>
    </schema>



    cqlsh> SELECT * from rawdata.test2 WHERE solr_query='content:我喜欢吃鱼';

     id | title      | content    | solr_query
    ----+------------+------------+------------
     簇 | 我喜欢吃鱼 | 我喜欢吃鱼 |       null

    (1 rows)
```

Maybe it is the data that causes problems OR the locale on your clusters / client?
Can you share the data in the text form?

Comment: I only using 2 simple data, you can check it in my post. I can not directly paste it in the post instead with a picture.
Maybe you guys should have a deep look. 
My DSE 6.7 is in a docker env.

Comment: I put test data here,thanks.

INSERT INTO rawdata.test (id,title, content) VALUES (1, '财政部', '国家税务总局关于第二批全国税务领军人才培养对象选拔笔试的通告');

INSERT INTO rawdata.test (id,title, content) VALUES (2,'国税局', '湖南省地方税务局转发国家税务总局关于印发《个人所得税专项检查工作规程（试行）》的通知');

Comment: I start DSE 6.7 with cassandra, spark, solr, graph.

Comment: I have a DSE Search only cluster, but this does not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the data provided and I am not able to reproduce.

I am attaching screenshot as SO editor has a bug (I have reported it).
[image]

Please notice that in case of StrField prefix has to be followed by a star, while with IKT it is not necessary.

So I am afraid this might be some environmental issue on your side, like cluster locale maybe? Hard to say.